# In python using Tkinter why isn't a new window opening under this IF statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, if-statement, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple GUI for an alarm using Tkinter and the sound plays when the imputed time is reached. However, it should also open a new window with a snooze button on it that when pressed waits five minutes before the sound goes off again. For some reason this new window doesn't open and the rest of the code runs without error and I just can't figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
if str(Time) == str(Alarm):

    winsound.PlaySound('Alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME) #Plays alarm sound

    GoingOff = Toplevel()   #Should open new window, why doesn't it open???
    GoingOff.geometry('309x225')    
    GoingOff.title('Wake Up')

    label2 = Label(GoingOff, text = '\nSnooze?')
    label2.pack()


    def Snooze5():   #Code for the snooze function to be called when the button is pressed.              
        time.sleep(300)
        winsound.PlaySound('Alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    Snooze5 = Button(GoingOff,font=("Helvetica", 16), text="Snooze for 5 minutes", width = 16, height = 4, command=Snooze5)
    Snooze5.pack()      

else:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: If you already have a window open, you should use a TopLevel widget to create a pop up box with a snooze button in it.

Comment: Try `GoingOff = Toplevel()` instead.

Comment: @Novel I just tried this and still no luck, I'm really stumped.

Comment: @JoshDinsdale I changed GoingOff = Tk() into GoingOff = Toplevel() and still no box. Really appreciate the help though.

Comment: You'll have to show us a [mcve] then.

Comment: Check my answer again, it should work now.

Comment: @Novel While trying to produce a Minimal version I found the issue. Thank you so much dude. Is there any way I can give you some sort of +rep or up vote.

Comment: LOL, yeah that happens a lot. Don't worry about the upvote. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you don't call `mainloop` for both Tk windows, however, you should use `TopLevel` to create pop up windows. In your case:

```
top = Toplevel()
top.geometry('309x225')
top.title('Wake Up')
label2 = Label(top, text = '\nSnooze?')
label2.pack()


def Snooze5():   #Code for the snooze function to be called when the button is pressed.
    top.after(300000, winsound.PlaySound('Alarm.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME))        

Snooze5 = Button(top, font=("Helvetica", 16), text="Snooze for 5 minutes", width=16, height=4, command=Snooze5)
Snooze5.pack()
```

Use `top.after()` to prevent the window from freezing.

Comment: `time.sleep(300)` will cause the entire GUI to freeze.

Comment: I've tried changing it to Toplevel() and still no luck. I thought for sure that was it after I saw you suggest it, but still nothing.

Comment: @JoshDinsdale I found the issue and it was entirely my fault, little mistake that I made earlier in the code I'm working on. Thanks so much for your help though. Is there a system in place so I can give you some sort of upvote or +rep?

Comment: The update doesn't do much here. It might cause the window to appear, but it  will still be frozen.

Comment: Have rectified using `top.after()` Bryan.